# How to check is it parameters in declare section equal to sysdate - stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have a problem with checking variables, when I try to convert those variables in date to check `if statement`, when creating `stored procedure`.

Code like this

```
 create or replace procedure test 
 as
   dan nvarchar2(2) :='1'; 
   mesec nvarchar2(2) := '1';
   godina nvarchar2(4) := '2016';
 begin
   if to_date(dan||mesec||godina,'dd-mon-yy') != sysdate
   then 
     for dan in 1..12 loop
       dbms_output.put_line(dan);
     end loop;
    end if;
 end;
```

These 3 variables are nvarchar2, what is needed by to_date function as a parameter. But when try to convert these variables to a date, and check is it equal to `sysdate`, give me next error

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: How about using the right conversion?  `'yyyymmdd'`?

Comment: can you convert sysdate to a string in the same format as the variable?

Comment: Format string you are using expects two digits day and month(`01 and 01`), thus the error. Besides, keep in mind that `sysdate` returns date **and time** so your `IF` condition may not work as you think it would.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I try now this `to_date(dan||mesec||godina,'yyyymmdd') != sysdate` and give me back error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Comment: @MarkD Good clue, i try next  `if godina||mesec||dan != to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')` and it work nicely. I am new to PL/SQL and didn't know that `nvarchar2` can be in loop, so have problem with that also

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Yea, i forgot that sysdate give that format. But I think that '01' is not the problem, because in `if godina||mesec||dan != to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')` give me output. But it's good point of view that I miss

Comment: @Smederevac do you want to put your complete solution in an answer just incase anybody else comes across the same issue?

Comment: @MarkD Yea, You have a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a rather long comment so I put it in the answer.

Now, let's start from the beginning. Why did you have that

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

in the first place.

Your final, representing date, string literal you had after concatenating different parts of the date looked like this

```
112016
```

Date format string (`dd-mon-yy`) used in the `to_date()` function expects day and month to be represented by two digits: day `01` and month `01` not `1` and `1` as is in your case. So for the `to_date()` function to be executed successfully it should've looked like this

```
to_date('01012016', 'dd-mm-yy')
```

NOT like this(your case)

```
to_date('112016', 'dd-mm-yy')
```

Then you would have to take time portion of the date into consideration when comparing those two dates - you would have to get rid of it by applying `TRUNC()` function to the `sysdate` (after that, time defaults to midnight, exactly what you need if you want to compare just two dates).

The condition becomes

```
to_date('01012016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') != trunc(sysdate)
```

If you wanted to go another way and convert `sysdate` to string and compare two string literals you  would also need either work with two digits day and month (`01` and `01` respectively) or leave the as they were (each one of them is represented by one digit) and use `FM` format modifier in the format string to get rid of leading zeros. So it would look either like this

```
declare
  dan nvarchar2(2) :='01'; 
  mesec nvarchar2(2) := '01';
  godina nvarchar2(4) := '2016';
begin
  if godina||mesec||dan != to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd'); 
  ...
end;
```

OR

```
declare
  dan nvarchar2(2) :='1'; 
  mesec nvarchar2(2) := '1';
  godina nvarchar2(4) := '2016';
begin
  if godina||mesec||dan != to_char(sysdate, 'fmyyyymmdd'); 
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Well this clarification explain me a lot. Is it possible to do like i try `if to_date(dan||mesec||godina,'dd-mon-yy') != sysdate`. Trying to convert parameters into date. Is that a good way?

Comment: @Smederevac Yes, it's possible. There is an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct way:

```
 create or replace procedure test 
 as
   dan nvarchar2(2) :='1'; 
   mesec nvarchar2(2) := '1';
   godina nvarchar2(4) := '2016';
 begin
  if godina||mesec||dan != to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')
   then 
     for dan in 1..12 loop
       dbms_output.put_line(dan);
     end loop;
    end if;
 end;
```

Comment: Once again. You need to work with two digits day and month or use `FM` format modifier to get rid of leading zeros in day and month. Otherwise, your  `IF` condition will always be evaluated to true. In this case, you are comparing `2016111`  to (suppose today is 01.01.2016 and `sysdate` returns this date) `20160101`, which will never be equal.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov How to overcome that obstacle? If i in declare section put variables to be '01'?

Comment: Since they are strings, yes. Or use `lpad(mesec,2,'0')` to left-pad with zeroes. If they were numbers you could use `to_char(mesec,'00')`.